# Drawing with replacement

Tags: probability

Start with an container with 20 white balls, 30 black balls, and 40 red balls.

If you draw 900 with replacement, what is the probability you draw between 390 and 410 red balls?

I have to use normal approximation, but I am not sure how to do it

Comment: So what are the values you would use for just straight binomial distribution?

Comment: Have you looked up the formulas for the [normal approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution#Normal_approximation)?  Where are you stuck?

Comment: I have a okay grasp at the concept of normal distribution, but I have no idea how to apply it in this scenario

Comment: Ignore the normal distribution for now.  Focus on the binomial distribution.  How many trials occur?  What counts as a "success" for each trial?  What is the probability of success for each trial?  What then is the expected number of successes?  What then is the standard deviation of the number of successes?

Comment: So would it be ( 900 choose 20) (.44)^20 (.56)^880 would be my interpretation of using a binomial distribution to solve this. I feel like this doesn't account for the between 390 and 410 though